# Why am I getting a "Input String was not in correct format" error?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have searched as much as I can and the only thing I can find are examples that have no relevance to my situation. So I came here. I am making a save editor and am trying to make the combo box option write to the save file. Well, it seems to get all the way to the point of writing it, but then it shoves the input string error at me. Here is the relevant code. Oh, and the first to characters of the combo box options are required hex values.

EDIT: I backtracked to when the string actually was a string

```
        string filename = textBox1.Text;

        //if comboBox1.SelectedIndex
        string comboxVal = comboBox1.Text;
        char[] chimney = new char[4];
        chimney[0] = '0';
        chimney[1] = 'x';
        comboxVal.CopyTo(0, chimney, 2, 2);


        string s = new string(chimney);
        label7.Text = s;
        FileStream fw = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        fw.Position = 0x684;
        fw.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(s));
        fw.Close();
```

Comment: which line throws?

Comment: Char and String in C# are two byte objects with a private property indicating if a character is one or two bytes.  You need to use an encoding type like Ascii, UTF7, UTF8, Unicode to properly convert to/from a byte array.  You are moving your stream position to 0x684 which is probably getting into the middle of a two byte character giving the error.

Comment: string compWrite = Convert.ToString(write);
        fw.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(compWrite));

Comment: Are you trying to convert hex string to byte? See [Convert.ToByte Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g. `fw.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(comboxVal, 16));`

Comment: Thanks Ivan Stoev. That is exactly what I was looking for. Even though I couldn't really phrase it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see whats happening here.

You have `char[] write`. An array of characters.

You call `string compWrite = Convert.ToString(write);`. The overload of `Convert.ToString(object value)` which accepts an object as an input is selected by compiler (you can check it by moving mouse cursor on top of `ToString`).

So `Convert.ToString(object)` is called and the result is `System.Char[]` which is stored in `compWrite`.

Now we have `Convert.ToByte(compWrite)` which tries to convert the string representation of a number into a integral variable of type byte. Any doubt that it fails with "**Input String was not in correct format**" error?